# strange issue with file_get_content for some urls!! - php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have an url and could scrap it using file_get_contents() and collect the links inside :

http://www.140online.com/Class/450/%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%B1%20%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%AA

this is the result array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => /company/C79955/المصرية ماركت - امام منصور امام/
    [1] => /company/C574901/مريم ماركت/
    [2] => /company/C1131/سوبر ماركت اولاد رجب/
    [3] => /company/C19699/البركه/
    [4] => /company/C21707/سوبر ماركت بست باى/
    [5] => /company/C23552/الشامل مى ماركت/
    [6] => /company/C21714/سوبر ماركت التميمى/
    [7] => /company/C171121/الجزيره/
    [8] => /company/C172099/الحمد ماركت/
    [9] => /company/C172325/الخشاب ماركت/
    [10] => /company/C174805/الدكان ماركت/
    [11] => /company/C183996/اسواق الشمس المركزيه/
    [12] => /company/C184039/اسواق مرحبا/
    [13] => /company/C189580/البحيرى ماركت/
    [14] => /company/C216371/سوق زمزم/
    [15] => /company/C216941/سيتى ارت/
    [16] => /company/C226223/وجينات محمد سعيد محمد موسى/
    [17] => /company/C297432/ماركت اولاد محمود/
    [18] => /company/C326553/سوبر ماركت عمرو عبد السلام سالم محمد/
    [19] => /company/C326566/سوبر ماركت عونى عزيز هنرى/
)
```

then I need to scrap each link to get some data but here is the problem !

to use any link I have to add the domain name before.

[http://www.140online.com/company/C79955/المصرية](http://www.140online.com/company/C79955/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9) ماركت - امام منصور امام/

but when I try to get it's contents it send me this error :

file_get_contents(http://www.140online.com/company/C79955/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%AA%20-%20%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

although I encode the Arabic part as it shown by explode:

```
    $url_ex = explode("/", $itm_url[$i]);
    $i_url = 'http://'.$url_ex[2].'/'.$url_ex[3].'/'.$url_ex[4].'/'.rawurlencode($url_ex[5]).'/';
```

the another strange thing is I can get contents for some links but not for all

please help

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with file_get_contents for web scraping. I would recommend to use CURL. This library returns HTTP error codes to know what kind of problem you have.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
```

This is an example how to use CURL, I hope it works.

```
$ch1 = curl_init('string_url');
$options1 = array(CURLOPT_POST => true,
                     CURLOPT_HEADER => $request_headers,
                     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,                     
                     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => (if u need to send params)
                    );
curl_setopt_array($ch1, $options1);
$page = curl_exec($ch1); 

if(curl_exec($ch1) === false)
{
    \print_r(curl_error($ch1));
    //HTTP and many other errors if you have it
}

curl_close($ch1);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
//Load Document Object Model
$dom->loadHTML($page); 
$domxPath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$urls = $domxPath->query("/html/body//div[@class='urls']"); 
//Example here searchs all divs which has urls class
//You need to specify which element of DOM contains URLS

//$urls variable must contains an array with urls that you need
```